# Terminology: Is Euclidean space theory Euclid geometry?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, terminology

A **Euclidean space** is an affine space over the reals such that the associated vector space is a finite-dimensional inner product over the real numbers.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space#Technical_definition

Is the theory of Euclidean space Euclidean geometry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That theory of Euclidean space is not "Euclidean geometry". Here is a better wikipedia page for [Euclidean geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry).

That link you posted is a great example of a bad wikipedia wiki page. The definition of Euclidean space in that link is a modern terminology that puts Euclid's name on a modern theory. It seems to be a standard definition, but not one I like personally. I would say that page you linked is confusing and conflating Euclidean geometry, Cartesian geometry, and the modern theory of vector spaces and affine spaces. Euclid did not even have coordinates.

Comment: "The definition of Euclidean space in your post, taken from that wikipedia page, is not a standard definition." It's one I've encountered in essentially that form in multiple classes, textbooks, and I think questions on MathSE. I think that while it's not something every book that mentions "affine space" would say, it's a pretty standard definition. The fact that Euclid didn't have coordinates has nothing to do with what modern definitions of "Euclidean space" can and can't be.

Comment: Point taken, and I rewrote my answer. I nonetheless do not like that usage of the term Euclidean space (and have been trying to stop using it in that fashion myself, with limited success).